# django: вывод данных в шаблоне по условию

Tags: python, html, django

Всем привет! Разрабатываю интернет магазин по сдаче авто в аренду. У каждого автомобиля есть по 4-6 фотографий. У меня проблема: я в django admin в БД загружаю, к примеру, 4 фото вместо 5 возможных, написав в модели `blank=True`, то есть фото становятся не обязательными. Так вот, я хочу, чтобы django выводил картинки, если они есть, а если их нет, то пропускал. Я пытался так:

```
{% if d.image5 %}
<div class="single-small-img">
   <img src="{{ d.image5.url }}" alt="Image">
</div>
{% endif %}
```

но django возвращает ошибку

```
ValueError at /catalog/product/3/
The 'image5' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это правильно сделать

Comment: видимо вам в условии нужно указать не просто объект (image), а конкретный его атрибут, в котором должна быть ссылка на изображение.